# How to cook sea bass fillet in foil in the oven from frozen

Tags: fish

I would like to cook a sea bass fillet from frozen and to cook it wrapped in foil, how should i do this? Because its frozen, how long should i have it in the oven for and at what temperature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply make a tightly sealed parcel of the foil by doubling it and folding over the fish and sealing the edges. I'd include some knobs of butter and lemon slices, and some fresh ground pepper.

As for cooking time, that really depends on the thickness of the fillet. I would say around 20-25 minutes at 180°C/350°F as a guide, but you should make sure the fish is piping hot throughout and opaque white with no translucent bits.

Comment: Thanks very much ElendilTheTall, regarding the foil should it have a gap between the top of the fillet and the foil, like space within the parcel?

Comment: It's not essential. If you put the lemon slices on top of the fish they will stop it sticking. The skin of the fish will stick to the foil, which is a good or a bad thing depending on whether you like to eat it or not! If you do, grease the foil a little beforehand.

Comment: Thanks ElendilTheTall, im looking forward to trying this.